# how to Open a Teams TaskModule from an adaptive card using manifest.json

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards, task-module

I am trying to open a taskmodule from an adaptive card. I have placed a button named task module and I am trying to open a task module when the button is clicked i want to know what i am doing wrong.[click here for code image preview][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIrY8.png

```html
{
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "size": "Medium",
      "weight": "Bolder",
      "text": "${title}"
    },
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "text": "${body}",
      "wrap": true
    }
  ],
  "actions": [
    {
      "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
      "title": "Bot Framework Docs",
      "url": "https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/?view=azure-bot-service-4.0"
    },
    {
      "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
      "title": "Teams Toolkit Docs",
      "url": "https://aka.ms/teamsfx-docs"
    },
    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "title": "Task Module",
      "data": {
        "msteams": {
          "type": "task/fetch"
        },
        "data": "{\"text\":\"Hello World\"}"
      }
      }
  ],
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "version": "1.4"
}
```